# Is there a way to speed up the calls to brew --prefix in my .bash_profile?

Tags: homebrew, bash

My `.bash_profile` Is taking a long time to load and I've narrowed the culprits down to these two lines:

```
export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55)/bin:$PATH"
. "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
```

It appears that the issue is `brew --prefix` is making a call to a homebrew server to get the values of these variables, though I'm not 100% sure. Is that why these two calls are taking so long? (I've confirmed it is not the call to `nvm.sh` that is taking a long time).

Is there perhaps a way to cache the results of these calls? I know I could simply hard-code the output of `brew --prefix` but I'd prefer not to as what happens if that changes at some point...or is that not going to be an issue?

Comment: How long does `brew --prefix` take on your machine then? It is near instant on mine.

Comment: @MarkSetchell `brew --prefix` is nearly instantaneous. It's the other commands like `brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55` that take time...presumably because they need to hit the homebrew server.

Comment: How long do they take please?

Comment: About 1-1.5 seconds each time they call `brew --prefix` something - about the same as an Http request. It's just annoying because it happens every time I start a new shell.

Comment: I don't believe it contacts the server - though you could easily test by pulling your network connection and seeing if it works. You could always assume a value to get your shell started quickly and then check it in the background and beep or change the desktop background red or pop up a messagebox if the assumption later proves incorrect.

Comment: related: https://superuser.com/questions/476540/homebrew-slows-my-terminal-down-on-startup and this (unfixed) issue: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/3327

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, the paths are reasonably consistent once the packages are installed, so it should be fine to hard-code the output. I've done this in my configuration without any trouble so far.

Just to be safe, you could do something like this, which would use `brew --prefix` only if the hardcoded directory doesn't exist:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/php55/bin" ]; then
    export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php55/bin:$PATH"
else
    export PATH="$(brew --prefix homebrew/php/php55)/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $HOMEBREW_PREFIX which is provided by `eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"`